# How can I solve this system (through approximate or exact methods)?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

I have a 4 equations 4 unknowns system as i attached it. I want to calculate T1, T2, P1 and P2 through solve this system and i have coded it in mathematica but it could not obtain the answer by solve command. Except this 4 unknowns, all of the other symbols are parameters and Gamma is a parameter equal or greater than 1. Can someone tell me how can i obtain mentioned variables values through any exact or approximate methods?
Thank you[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uQBHJ.png)

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things 
about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if 
you write what your thoughts 
are on the problem and include your efforts (work in progress) in 
this and future posts and in what context you have encountered the problem; this will prevent people 
from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers 
at the right level.
This site uses
[MathJax formatting](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation)

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce the system of $4$ equations in $4$ unknowns to a system of $2$ equations in $2$ unknowns, either by eliminating $p_1$ and $p_2$ through linear superposition (as they only occur linearly) or by solving ($11$) for $T_1$ and ($12$) for $T_2$ and substituting into ($9$) and ($10$). In either case the resulting equations will be transcendental, and you'll probably need to solve them numerically; but that might be significantly easier than solving the original system.